# Moving a Linked Library

Tags: linked-data

Is there a way, after a library is linked to move that library to another location? I have a library that is in a different folder than my scene file and for the sake of more easily sending it to a renderfarm I want to move it all into one folder. Is there a way to edit link paths?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. At the outliner panel, find **blender File** in the menu.

[image]

You will see then the current file listed along with other linked files. You can edit the path by clicking over it twice with the left mouse button, or using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ left mouse over it.

[image]

You must rewrite the new access path yourself. Save and reload to apply the changes.
WARNING !! DO backup before you do this! If the linked file is not found, the result will be a broken file without the link. If you save again with that error, you will loose any reference (instances to that file) forever, forcing you to relink again.

Comment: In my testing, @gabrign's answer works if you change the path BEFORE the master blend becomes broken. So to move/rename a library blend you have to duplicate it, move/rename it, and only delete the original after you have updated the master blend/s file path as explained. This doesn't solve fixing blends with broken asset links and is cumbersome overall.

Comment: Thanks for share. I not test it by myself, but is good know it.

Comment: Thankfully this has been fixed in Blender 2.77. You can now fix it even AFTER the file becomes broken. In the Blender 2.77 release notes it says that "In case of missing libraries on load(sic), empty placeholder datablocks get added, which allows to(sic) restore or relink." and in the Datablocks and Libraries Management section of the release notes it says that this allows the user to "Edit missing libs paths(sic) in the Outliner, save & reload main .blend file, and get missing linked datablocks back." Source: https://www.blender.org/features/2-77/

Answer (score -1):

With the [Project Glue](https://blendermarket.com/products/project-glue) addon, you can move library files and have the users be automatically updated to avoid broken references.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/175452)