# Changing only one linked group Original File

Tags: blend-files, linked-data, groups

I've linked several groups from one file to another. But after i wanted to change one group's original file to another. In which I was successful by changing the blend file path in the outliner following this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13800/moving-a-linked-library), however when I do so. all the other linked groups disappear (which make sense).

The question : is there a way to change the original file of only one linked group ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand correctly.

If it's not the file itself you need to change but the content I think it would be easiest to simply select group and copy+paste selection to the file replacing the group/objects there.