# How to re-link missing blender files

Tags: linked-data, file-browser

I have multiple characters linked to a blender file, but i moved the original character files and now blender is sating they're missing.

Is it possible to get blender to find the missing blender files like it finds missing image files so that i can preserve the previously made animation?

On a side note is there a way to also view a list of all the missing files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it possible to get blender to find the missing blender files like
>   it finds missing image files so that i can preserve the previously
>   made animation?

Yes, totally. Go to "*File > External Data > Find missing files*".
You can navigate to specific folders if you know where you put your files. as blender searches sub-directories you can even say: "Hey blender, my file is somewhere in here, just look for yourself" on your documents folder.

> On a side note is there a way to also view a list of all the missing
>   files?

Yes. There is.
"*File > External Data > Report missing files*" prints all missing files to the console (in the default layout you can all down the menu on the top to see the console's content.)

[image]

Comment: thanks I also found out that even though the characters weren't showing initially after finding them, if i saved and re-opened the file they loaded fine

Comment: And would you replace a linked file ? I mean what if you want to use a file that do not have the same filename ?

Answer (score 7):

As in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13815/38130), if the file name has changed as well, you can change it in the Outliner by going to `Blender File`:

[image: Blender File view]

There you should find the broken link:

[image: Broken link]

Double-click the file path to edit it, then right-click on it and select `Reload` and the link should be restored.

[image: Edit link]

[image: Restored]