# Broken link lib

Tags: linked-data

I usually used "append" when I using a rig in different scenes and different project.
This week I used "link object" and then "make proxy"
I've just move the work in another HD, and I can't open anything.
Is there a way to relink like 7 rigs in 7 scenes…

It seems to be tricky in blender…

please tell me I can't have my one week work back 
g.

Comment: Hello :). Just go *File > External Data > Find missing files* https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/96587/

Comment: Finally fix it from the outliner/blender file/relocate/