# How can I send someone a .blend file with cache folder included?

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation, blend-files, cache

I've been trying to send a person my .blend file with an external cache folder (.bphys format) to render a fire for me, and when he opens it, he can't connect the two. Any solutions?

Comment: Use [relative paths](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56683/moving-all-files-to-a-new-computer-my-concern-is-links) also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96587/how-to-re-link-missing-blender-files

Answer (score 1):

Set blender to use relative paths.

Copy the folder with the cache on the same folder as the blend file.

Pack all the images used as textures.

Zip the folder with all those files into a single compressed file.

Send the zip file.

Comment: So put the .blend and cache folder into one folder together, then zip that? And set blender to File>External Data>Automatically Pack into .blend AND File>External Data>Make all paths relative?

Comment: It is important that the cache folder is in a subfolder. No need to rename it,

Comment: Ok got it, sitting alongside the .blend file correct?

Comment: Sitting or standing or laying. As long as they are together nice and cozy.

Comment: Ahaha thank you :)