# Packing all linked Files for Render Farm submission

Tags: rendering, linked-data, packed-data, packing

So I want to submit a project to a renderfarm. I have multiple links to other .blend files in the project since this saves memory and speeds up the render a lot. The blend files are roughly 5 GB combined. it is a large scene.

Is there a way to easily package all associated files for submission to the renderfarm?
The pack all into blend function only works for textures for as far as I know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177624/how-can-i-send-someone-a-blend-file-with-cache-folder-included/177631#177631

Answer (score 0):

You should try this option:
Object=>Relations=>Make Local=>All

[image]

Unfortunately, it does not work for proxies. At least it didn't some time ago.

As for the render farm, you can try GarageFarm.NET. Their plugin uses this option automatically.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)