# finding a link or material pointing to a missing file or path

Tags: packing

In packing a blend file I get a report of 3 missing files (actually, only paths) from an FBX imported from a 3dsMax export:

```
Error: Unable to pack file, source path 'C:\Users\James\Documents\3dsMax\projects\architecture\scenes' not found
```

(aside: this path actually exists)
I am not getting any console output in 2.90 for ["List Missing Files"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/96607/111042).   Is there some way I can discover what material or other file pointer are causing these errors so that I can correct them?

Answer (score 1):

In the outliner choose the *Orphan Data* display mode

[image]

To fix the path for broken links or missing items use the *Data Api* mode

> **Data API**
> Lists every [data-block](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/data_blocks.html) along with any properties that they might have.
> **Orphan Data**
> Lists [data-blocks](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/data_blocks.html) which are unused and/or will be lost when the file is reloaded. It includes data-blocks which have only a fake user. You can add/remove Fake User by clicking on cross/tick icon in the right side of the Outliner editor.

([from the blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner/interface.html))