# Models colors are not visible just an outline

Tags: color

I downloaded a blender model and opened it in blender. There are no colours. I need to see the fully colored model so I can import it into pshop. Any help would be appreciated.
[image: wizard]

Comment: The pink color indicates that the texture is missing, this is why you cannot see the colors on the model. Either you have to go into the material shader and there probably is an image texture node where you manually ahve to add the image texture which might you might have somewhere separately in the download folder, or the texture is missing because it wasn't contained in the download.

Comment: Oh - I just read this too. Excellent - you are right. Thanks. You appeard as a comment.

Comment: Yes, I appeared as a comment because I commented on it  :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever blender shows a model in pink color, it means the texture file or an image is missing from that model. Also, sometimes blender fails to link the a texture file.

You can go to **File > External data > Find missing files** and browse for the location to recover them.

For detail instructions on how to link a texture or image file you may refer to this thread [How to re-link missing blender files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96587/how-to-re-link-missing-blender-files)

Comment: Thank you so much Rose.